# Buying a defect mobile

Tags: fraud, germany

Recently, I bought a used mobile with invoice from a woman (i found the mobile in internet, and in the invoice she took off the part where is her name and address).
As usual, I kept all discussions which was made between us so that I can use it in the case there is a problem in the future.
In the first, I didn't start to use the mobile only after 1 week (I was waiting for glass protector which i ordered). In her ad, she mentioned that the mobile is working 100% without any problem, and even after discussing that face to face she agreed this point.
Now, and just after using this mobile for 2 days, I figured out that this mobile has some problems (the opposite to what she said), as it turns sometimes off from alone, and sometimes displaying screen color problems ( in 2 days i got those problems 2 or 3 times).
I went to phone repair shop, and he told me he can't figure out the problem, as it is not happening each minute or hour.
I discussed with her and I told her all what happened, but she just said that the mobile was 100% ok and it is me who damaged it and I don't want it now.
**Question**
Do I have the right to go to police and to get my money back from her?

Comment: §433 - §453 BGB([de](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/BJNR001950896.html#BJNR001950896BJNG024101377)|[en](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_bgb/englisch_bgb.html#p1551)) would be relevant in this situation.

Comment: my problem is about period, I know that in Germany you have the right to give it back in such case, but after more than 10 days, I am not quite sure.